# Firebase custom user claims are not set

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am trying to add custom user claims after user sign up, to define user role, using *setCustomUserClaims*:

/api/users/addUser.js

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  const { displayName, email, password, role } = req.body;

  if (!displayName || !password || !email || !role) {
    return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Missing fields' });
  }

  try {
    const { uid } = await admin.auth().createUser({
      displayName,
      email,
      password,
    });
    await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, role);
    res.status(201).send(uid);
  } catch (error) {
    handleError(res, error);
  }
};
```

This code checks for any change in the authentication state and sets *user* to the currently logged in user:

/utils/use-auth.js

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser(false);
        // Router.push('/login');
      }
    });
```

in my */pages/user/home,jsx*:

```
import { useAuth } from '../../utils/use-auth';

function home() {
  const { user } = useAuth();

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(user, null, 4)}</pre>
        <AdminLayout componentProps={{ selected: '1' }} Component={HomeContent} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The displayed object doesn't have any custom claims.
when I check the firebase console, I find that the user is actually added.

Comment: How did you check whether they propagated? The client only sees the updated claims once it refreshes its ID token, which happens automatically once per hours, or when you force a refresh.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen actually I did not explain the issue clearly, I meant they don't get set

Comment: There's not enough information here.  Please edit the question to: 1) check for errors and show any error messages, 2) illustrate clearly what claims you're trying to set, 3) explain how you are observing that the code isn't working the way you expect.  I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson I added more details

Comment: So what **exactly** are you observing that suggests the claims are not set?  Are you expecting `JSON.stringify(user, null, 4)}` to show this somehow?  There is a specific API for accessing custom claims from a user object - use that instead.

Comment: @DougStevenson it works, I used the API to get user claims

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, claims).then(() => {
// Do your stuff here
});
```

And verify the claims like

```
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then((claims) => {
// check claims
  if (claims) { 
  // do your stuff here
  }
});
```

for more info check https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#node.js

Comment: Actually, in my userRecord object I can't find any field named customClaims

Comment: You won't find the claims in user object but in the token and  verify the claims like the above

Comment: You can also check the claims from client. Please check https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#javascript

Comment: @AbdullahToufiq can we also set claims from the client side or not?

Comment: @UmairA. you can access the claims but  can not set claims from client